# What can I do if my battery stops charging halfway?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, drivers, battery

Two days ago i bought a new extended battery 8800mAh for my CompaQ Presario C700. At first it worked good and possibly is still, but what i have noticed is that my Windows 7 Sees it as normal 6 cell battery with 4800mAh battery. After uninstalling and reinstalling "Microsoft Composite Battery" driver windows did recognize it as extended 12 cell battery but the problem is that it only charges till 4800mAh and after it reches 51% it says: "Connected, Plugged in, Not charging".

Maybe i need to specify somewhere that the battery is extended or maybe i need to install specific driver?

Please help as it maybe possible for it to damage my new battery which indeed last 4-5 hours even while playing action.

This is the battery: [http://www.amazon.com/Anker-Replacement-compatible-DV6000-DV2000/dp/B003L0RMK2/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1295650562&sr=8-10](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003L0RMK2)

Answer (score 1):

I have had that problem with a dell computer and a simple bios update fixed it.

Comment: This is the more likely solution to the problem, although it is possible, as @w7pro says, that the battery is damaged.

Comment: I did update bios but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the battery came in damaged. This has actually happened to me when I ordered a replacement battery for an old laptop. Amazon simply sent me a new battery. However, if you're still unsure, you could change the battery settings and see if that helps at all.

Comment: Battery is in good condition this problem came up just after i reinstalled the windows composite battery driver